# My code is not switching to the desired function depending upon the selection from combo box c#

Tags: c#, combobox

The code is not invoking the show_auto function even though I have selected the CHEMICAL from the drop down, it is always invoking the show_cement function.

```
private void gunaComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ArrayList companyName = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList Price = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList category = new ArrayList();

    String selected = this.gunaComboBox1.GetItemText(this.gunaComboBox1.SelectedItem);

    if (selected.Equals("CHEMICAL")) {
        show_auto(companyName, Price, selected);
    } else {

        show_cement(companyName, Price, "CEMENT");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and examined the value of `selected` before you test it?

Comment: You must have miss spelled "CHEMICAL" in the combo box. Make sure the case matches and there are no spaces at the beginning or end of the word "CHEMICAL" in the combobox. I tested this and it works, so long as the combobox has "CHEMICAL" in it.

Comment: @JesseChunn you are right actually it was " CHEMICAL" with space at the beginning that was causing the condition to fail. Thanks for the insight

Comment: Excellent. Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String selected = gunaComboBox1.selecteditem.text;
```

and then compare with "CHEMICAL"